# NOT gate circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, boolean-algebra

How exactly in a NOT gate circuit turning the switch 'OFF' is going to turn the bulb 'ON' and vice versa? I mean in OR and AND gate Circuit the truth table makes sense - how we get the output. But for NOT gate I don't find any reason that explains the output

Comment: I don't understand your question. " for NOT gate I don't find any reason that explains the output". *By definition* a NOT gate inverts it input. If it doesn't, then it wasn't a NOT gate to begin with.

Comment: ...and what bulb is he talking about?

Comment: I mean...lets think about the and gate. The truth table is - output gonna be 1 only if all the inputs are 1. In The circuit of AND gate, for example, you connect 2 switches (input) and a resistance as output (I assumed a bulb) in series. Right? Clearly the bulb would turn on (1) only if both switche 1, switch 2 are turned on.  Just like the truth table. I can explain the OR gate same way but with the two switches in parallel. But i cant explain the NOT gate like that. How on earth when u let the current flow, the output is 0 (bulb off) and when u don't let go, output 1-light bulb is on!

Comment: The output power doesn't come directly from the gate input, hence why AND and NOR gates make sense to you. The voltage for the output pins is supplied front the VDD rail - I think that's what you mean

Comment: It either works because the NOT gate is attached to a power supply and there is some inverting electronics inside or because black magic does exist.

Answer (score 1):

Consider CMOS inverter:

[image]

whenever A is 'Low'/'0', NMOS is off and PMOS is ON which cause Flow of Vdd to output making it high.

You are probably thinking that if input is low then how can ouput be high i.e. how gate got the input power to make it high.
Answer is that transistors always has **Biasing**.

Answer (score 1):

You used the switch model to describe how `AND` and `OR` gates work. Your model just works with closing switches (*closer*). The switch model has also the opening switch (*opener*).

So a `NOT` gate can be modeled by an opener by connecting the input to the supply voltage and the output to the gates output.

**To be more precise:** Your two switch replacement circuit for `AND` and `OR` needs either pullup/pulldown resistors or two more switches to work correct. Otherwise it will leave the output floating in some cases.

Using 4 switches for `AND` and `OR` or 2 switches for `NOT` will solve the problem. It is called complementary logic as in *PMOS + NMOS => CMOS*.

So you need two switches: an *opener* and a *closer* to model the `NOT` gate. The *opener* is connected to supply voltage and the *closer* is connected to ground (GND). Both outputs are connected and wired to the gate's output. Both switches are switched simultaneously by the gate's input.

Finally, here are the switch based replacement circuits for common gates. It uses closing switches and resistors:

[image](clickable)

Answer (score 0):

The NOT gate you are talking about is at a higher **abstraction level** more like a black box concept.

These logic gates are actually made up of transistors which are properly biased to work in saturation and cutoff regions ( in simple terms: ON condition and OFF condition).

**WORKING:** (in simple terms)

The input you provide to the NOT gate is to an input transistor whose output is almost shorted to ground voltage (0 v)  when input is HIGH.

Similarly when you input a low voltage the transistor does not turn ON,leaving its output terminal clamped at high voltage (probably at the bias voltage).

**Biasing** : it's a term used to signify that the transistor terminals are provided with appropriate voltages using power supplies and resistors to make it work the way we want.

Note: If you haven't learnt about transistors,go through its basics (its fun).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have just started to know about Information and communication technology. I have no idea about anything. I started with the number system and logic gates. Maybe I started with the wrong topic. I don't know what VSS VDD Biasing or anything. I only have some simple concepts about what change these gates do to the input. I think when i will learn more i will understand it better. thanks everyone though :)